# <form:form have method GET or POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

This may be a very basic question but I am confused. I have couple of doubts:

1. In spring form `<form:form` if method is not specified then is it GET or POST?
2. If a spring form has `<form:form` with commandName then is that GET or POST?

The second question is because I see a "form:form commandName=xyz action=abc" in the code 
When I check the HTML code (view source) it translates to 
"form action=abc method=POST"

Please help me with this.

Comment: @sp00m a normal HTML form is always defaulted to GET.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But for HTML form default is POST. So does the <form:form of Spring default POST or is it due to CommandName?

Comment: @user1630693 its get, and spring is the same

Answer (score 5):

HTML `form` without specified action is always GET. It's HTML standard. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

But when you look inside `FormTag` in Spring source you'll notice this code:

```
public class FormTag extends AbstractHtmlElementTag {

/** The default HTTP method using which form values are sent to the server: "post" */
private static final String DEFAULT_METHOD = "post";
```

So for spring tag `<form:form` action is post by default.

`commandName` is just name for model attribute binded with your form. It has nothing to method type. Moreover, it's equivalent to `modelAttribute` so you can use either.

Comment: Ok then I didnt get that why I am getting method="POST" in my HTML code.

Comment: Also [documented in the API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.M5/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.html#DEFAULT_METHOD).

Comment: Why is the form needed in a simple get request? I have a JSP page that just loops a list and displays the name of the elements. The loop was inside a <form:form> tag, but after I removed it, it still works the same.

Answer (score 0):

Spring form has default method as POST. If you want to do the get, you have to write, method="get" in form:form tag.